# Querying in mongoexport through python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, mongoexport

Can Anyone explain how to export the result of a query with mongoexport inside a program in python ?

```
os.system('mongoexport -d fintapp -c portfolio --csv --fields userid,budget --query {"budget":{$exists:True}} -o fulbudg.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
os.system('''mongoexport -d fintapp -c portfolio --csv --fields userid,budget --query '{"budget":{$exists:True}}' -o fulbudg.csv''')
```

You need quotations around the query, and they have to be different from the other quotations you have used. In python there are 4 different ways of quoting: 
'quote',
"quote",
'''quote''',
"""quote"""

Answer (score -2):

Use subprocess

```
import subprocess


subprocess.call("mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --out output_fileName.csv type csv --fields name_of_columns", shell = True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your answer to include a proper formatted code. Also the OP wants an explanation not two words with code.

Comment: this is not working with Linux distrib => prefer the os.system method