# Is there a way to use Mongoexport with Airflow?

Tags: python, mongodb, airflow

I am trying to write Airflow DAG which will export data from certain collection in the MongoDB database. Is there any way to use Mongoexport with the Airflow?

I was thinking of something like this, based on airflow documentation:

```
def exportFromMongoCollection():
    try:
        hook = MongoHook(mongo_conn_id=f"mongodb://{os.environ.get('MUSER_NAME', None)}:{os.environ.get('MPASSWORD', None)}@{os.environ.get('HOST_IP', None)}:PORT/?authSource=admin")
        client = hook.get_conn()
        db = client.mongo_db_dev
        mongo_col=db.mongo_col
        print(f"Connected to MongoDB - {client.server_info()}")
        mongo_col.export() #need to figure out export here
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MongoDB -- {e}")

with DAG(
    'mongodbexport',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='mongodbexport',
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",
    catchup=False,
    tags=['export','mongodb'],
) as dag:

    t0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='export-mongodb',
        python_callable=exportFromMongoCollection,
        dag=dag
        )
```

But I am not sure how to call mongoexport there in the python code, which would do the same operation as the following command (example):

```
mongoexport --uri="URI" --collection=mongo_col type json --out=mongo_col.json
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mongo but have you tried using the [BashOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/bashoperator) to execute your command? You'd have to set `cwd` to the directory you want the bash command to run in and store the json output.
Alternatively, on a quick search I mostly found users using `os.system` in python code to use mongoexport (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277709/querying-in-mongoexport-through-python))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the collection and store the exported file on a remote storage service (S3), you can use [MongoToS3Operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/mongo_to_s3.py#L39) from the AWS provider, and you can extend it and implement the method [trnsform](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/mongo_to_s3.py#L145) to transform the data before writing them to S3 if needed.

If not, you can take inspiration from the source code to implement your own operator:

```py
if self.is_pipeline:
    results = MongoHook(self.mongo_conn_id).aggregate(
        mongo_collection=self.mongo_collection,
        aggregate_query=cast(list, self.mongo_query),
        mongo_db=self.mongo_db,
        allowDiskUse=self.allow_disk_use,
    )

else:
    results = MongoHook(self.mongo_conn_id).find(
        mongo_collection=self.mongo_collection,
        query=cast(dict, self.mongo_query),
        projection=self.mongo_projection,
        mongo_db=self.mongo_db,
    )
```